# FLURRY with android

Tags: android, flurry

i need to integrate flurry on my app and i want to know how to do it , i tried with some tuto but dosen't work,  please if some one can help me , and thank you . 
 this is what i used on manisfest :

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.mobiblanc.wydadnews.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

Comment: You need to post your code, otherwise there's not much we can do to help you.

Comment: yes but i want just what can i do , i use 
FlurryAgent.logEvent("");
that's what i did

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this blog post I wrote on how to integrate error reporting services (as `BugSence` and `Crittercism`) and usage monitoring services (`Flurry`) in your application:

[Error Reports and Usage Monitoring](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=630)

I'm sure you will find it useful.

Comment: @Kira, you welcome, consider accepting the answer if this guide helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the [official documentation](http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Analytics/GettingStarted/Android) available on Flurry's website for integrating the Flurry SDK in your Android app.

(Full disclosure: I work in the Support team at Flurry)

Answer (score 0):

You will have fixed it by now but for anyone else looking I integrated Flurry yesterday and after downloading the SDK I followed the instructions in the Support section of their website and was getting errors.

Make sure to follow the instructions that you download in the SDK package, taking note of any additions to proguard.cfg if you're using Proguard. After I followed them it worked perfectly